# Hide a view container with a button in the ViewContainer

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, uicontainerview

I have a `View`. In this view, I have a `Container View`. And in the `ContainerView` I have a button.

When I am touching the button of the ContainerView, I want the ContainerView become hidden.

I want to do something like that :

```
class ContainerView: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func closeContainerViewButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        //I try this : self.hidden = false
        //or this :    self.setVisibility(self.INVISIBLE)
    }

}
```

Any idea how do it?

Comment: Try to hide the view, view controller doesn't have these properties because it is not part of UI.

Comment: But I don't want to hide all the view, but the container view only...

Comment: Problem is that ContainerView is not a view - bad naming makes it more difficult to understand. The key part of `UIViewController` class name is `Controller` - it helps you to control a view.

Comment: I can change to have an `UIViewController` ? And if i do it, is it possible to hide itself ?

Comment: It won´t work to hide the view inside the container view. You have to call the UIViewController that owns (holding) the container view and tell it to hide the container view. When you hide the container view your view inside the container view will be hidden too. Lots of views in this text, I know. :)

Comment: lol :)
Thank you @rilar. And how do you call the `UIViewController`(parent) from the `ContainerView`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are serval ways but here is the easiest one, not prettiest though. You should really use delegates but this is a hacky way to get started. Just create a global variable of the class that holds the container (startController in this case). Then call it from your other view controller (MyViewInsideContainer) and tell it to hide the view you´re in. I have not run this code but it should work.

```
var startController = StartController()

class StartController:UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var myViewInsideContainerView: UIView

    ....

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        startController = self
    }

    func hideContainerView(){
        self.myContainerView.hidden = true
    }
}

class MyViewInsideContainer:UIViewController {

    ...

    @IBAction func hideThisView(sender: AnyObject) {
        startController.hideContainerView()
    }

}
```

Comment: First, Thank you @rilar. (Just, to be exact, it's my container which is in an `UIViewController`and it is the Container I want to hide :) )! 
Otherwise, It look right but one question : If i do like this, the two class are in the same swift file right ? So, if my container is "linked" to 2 different `UIVIewController`, Have I to right the class declaration in all of my class files concerned ?

Comment: No problem! You should put the classes in separate swift files. You will be able to access startController from anywhere since it´s placed outside the class StartController {}. If you hide the myViewInsideContainerView (which is the container of the UIViewController) you will also hide the UIViewController in it. Please accept the answer if this helped you.

Comment: Thank you very much ! It helped me, I was going to do it ;)

Answer (score 9):

i think a cleaner solution is to use delegation:

in the ParentViewController

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController ,ContainerDelegateProtocol
{
@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    //check here for the right segue by name
    (segue.destinationViewController as ContainerViewController).delegate = self;
}
func Close() {
        containerView.hidden = true;
    }
```

in the ContainerViewController

```
protocol ContainerDelegateProtocol
{
    func Close()
}
class ContainerViewController: UIViewController {


    var delegate:AddTaskDelegateProtocol?

    @IBAction func Close(sender: AnyObject) { //connect this to the button
        delegate?.CloseThisShit()

    }
```

Comment: ...but how do I connect the containerView with the ContainerViewController?  The containerView is a, well, a UIView which does not have a viewController, right?  What (simple thing) am I missing?

Comment: in the example above the connection is done in the prepareForSegue function (setting the delegate).