# IOS view container: how to set the delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, delegates, uicontainerview

All, my question is a follow up to this one: [SWIFT - Hide a view container with a button in the ViewContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25473913/swift-hide-a-view-container-with-a-button-in-the-viewcontainer)

In short, I have a UIViewController (Main) that contains a button "SHOW" and a containerView.  The container view ("containerView") has a single button "HIDE".   Initially the containerView is hidden, and when the "SHOW" button is tapped, it is displayed.  All is well.  I want to use a delegate such that when the "HIDE" button is tapped, the containerView will be hidden.

I understand all the delegate stuff, EXCEPT how does the containerView become a viewController so that I can assign Main to be the delegate?

The container view is a UIView which (somehow) points to / contains a view controller, but I cannot determine how to reference it.

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController,dismissPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var pickerContainerView: containerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var showButton: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pickerContainerView.hidden = true
    }

    @IBAction func showButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        println("+Show")
        pickerContainerView.hidden = false
        println("-Show")
    }

    func dismissPicker()
    {
        println("+dismissPicker")
        println("-dismissPicker")
    }
}


// ========================

import UIKit

protocol dismissPickerViewDelegate {
    func dismissPicker()
}

class pickerViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate : dismissPickerViewDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var hideButton: UIButton!
    @IBAction func hideButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        println("+hideButtonTapped")
        delegate?.dismissPicker()
        println("-hideButtonTapped")
    }
}
```

output: 
+Show
-Show
+hideButtonTapped
-hideButtonTapped

TIA,
:bp:

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't need to be a view controller in order to allow assignment of a delegate. The delegate is just a property of an object. Simply do this in your view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pickerContainerView.delegate = self
    pickerContainerView.hidden = true
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but : I get an error: 'containerView' does not have a member named 'delegate'  (I know this has to be pilot error, but... I don't see it)

Comment: Sorry; I misunderstood your code. It's very difficult to follow. I had just assumed that you made `pickerContainerView` a `pickerViewController`. How is `containerView` related to anything?

Comment: It is essentially an empty subclass of UIView.  If I change the @IBOutlet weak var pickerContainerView: containerView! to IBOutlet weak var pickerContainerView: UIView!  I get the same thing: UIView does not have a member named 'delegate'.

Comment: Of course it doesn't. Your `pickerViewController` has that property. Where are you creating `pickerViewController` such that you can cause `hideButtonTapped` after `showButtonTapped`?

Comment: hence my confusion.  I created this on a storyboard.  The item in the 'Main' view controller is a UIView object.  It is (somehow) connected to the pickerViewController, but how to reference it is the part that I am missing.

Comment: Let me reword my question. How does `pickerViewController` appear on screen?

Comment: The view controller is created when the app starts (loadViewIfRequired), it is hidden (pickerContainerView.hidden = true) in viewDidLoad.  pickerContainerView.hidden = false (which causes the view/controller to appear is called when 'SHOW' is tapped.  I have NOT done anything explicitly with pickerViewController, which is why I'm confused.  (Thanks for your help/patience)

Comment: errata: on the storyboard, the view controller that is connected to the container (embedded) , is cast as a pickerViewController

Comment: "The view controller is created when the app starts (loadViewIfRequired),". Save a reference to it and set your `MainViewController` as its delegate. Until you finally actually show the code that I've asked for, this is all just guesswork.

Comment: the entire code base is shown above (except the generated appdelegate, and whatever is generated by the storyboard).

Comment: What is the method that you have used to present the `pickerContainerView` on screen? How is `pickerContainerView` attached to anything? Where does its reference come from? Do you have a `pickerViewController` instance anywhere in your app code / storyboard? You are leaving out a lot of the most important details here and are missing the point of my questions.

Comment: I am sorry.  the pickerContainerView is created at launch (i do nothing explicitly to do this).  It is displayed when it is unhidden (hidden=false).  The pickerContainerView is an IBOutlet from MainViewController.  It (pCV) is a 'containerView'.  The connections Inspector shows a 'embed picker view controller' under the triggered segues for ViewDidLoad.  There are no other references to pickerViewController.  I appreciate your time and help but I don't wish to waste it.  Perhaps you should go back to work:) I'll tilt at my own windmill .  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your ViewController have Any ContainerView, then ViewController call `prepareForSegue` after `awakeFromNib`

this called before `viewDidLoad`

so you can set delegate in

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
```

First

Set your EmbededSegue Identifier

[image]

Second set your delegate to embededVC in prepareForSegue Function

[image]

Finally in your EmbededViewController call hide function to MainViewController
[image]